# Adding "Everywhere" to country_select

Tags: jquery

I am using [country_select plugin](https://github.com/mrmarkfrench/country-select-js)

I've been trying to add a custom field called "Everywhere" or "Worldwide" onto my select.

Currently, I have:

```
$("#country").countrySelect({
  defaultCountry: "Worldwide",
  preferredCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ca'],
  responsiveDropdown: true
});
```

- Doesn't seem to be any built-in functions
- I'm terrible as jQuery, so forgive me if I'm being incredibly silly.

Comment: please show your effort and research in solving this problem

Comment: it seems that there is no proper method for adding custom option in this, you can raise an issue on github in order to get authors and programmer's attention

Comment: your only chance is to manipulate the code and create your own version of the plugin. Otherwise ask the plugin author to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate country data with

```
var countryData = $.fn.countrySelect.getCountryData();
```

You can easily add custom countries:

```
countryData.push({
    name: "Worldwide",
    iso2: "ww",
});
```

After manipulation, update country data

```
$.fn.countrySelect.setCountryData(countryData);
```

Call this before calling for your input.

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute genius. Any chance of improving the answer slightly with including how to assign a flag to 'Worldwide'?

Comment: @GerryHodson There is a png image file which contains all flags. Flags are ordered alphabetically. Considering that we add worldwide to the end of the countries; if you append your worldwide flag to the very right of flags.png, you can see the flag (note that there is two image files for flags).